# wev2py 1.99.2: saving sessions to database

Tags: session, web2py

In web2py version 1.99.2, at the beginning of default.py controller I wrote the following:

```
session.connect(request, response, db, masterapp=None)
```

I'm using sql server 2008 express edition. In db.py I have:

```
db = DAL('mssql://sa:mypass@.\SQLEXPRESS/mytest')
```

Now, sessions are created in the database as expected. Then in default.py controller I added:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def test():
    return dict()
```

Also, default/test.html view was created. But, when I try to browse to the default/test.html page it redirects to the user/login page. The problem goes away, if I switch to the default file-based session. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try moving

```
session.connect(request, response, db, masterapp=None)
```

to db.py, right after you define the db connection. When `auth` is defined (I assume you have defined it in db.py or another model file), it needs to have access to the session, so you have to connect to the session first.